# snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true) returns an empty view

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, transition, navigationcontroller

I want to implement a custom push-transition for a navigation controller.

I first implemented the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` where I return an Object of `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`.

In this class, I want to take a *snapshot* of the destination view in order to animate it. However, for the push-segue, this doesn't work - the snapshot ist empty. [*when I pop back, I set `afterScreenUpdates = false` and everything works*]

```
    guard let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from),
        let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to) else {
            return
    }

    guard let snapshot = toVC.view.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true) else {
        return }

   // Problem:
   // snapshot is an empty view!
```

Comment: The same for me, did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Supplying **true** for -snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates: means it needs a trip back to the runloop to actually draw the image. If you supply NO, it will try immediately, but if your view is off screen or otherwise hasn't yet drawn to the screen, the snapshot will be empty.

Comment: „*it means it needs a trip back to the runloop to actually draw the image*“ - do you have a hint how to achieve this?

Comment: @Pascal you can achieve this using true, but if you want to see image immediately you should use false for -snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:

Answer (score 0):

I find that it is necessary to introduce a short delay, say about a tenth of a second, after the push transition and before taking the screenshot, in order to avoid the blank screenshot. Probably this lets the interface settle down in some way.